# Adding an event dynamically to a calendar

Tags: java, android, calendar

Im coding an app where I can create events and they will display in the calendar with the title and description I wrote. Problem is I can't seem to create them without overwriting the previous one. Every solution I tried just keeps overwriting them or just doesn't work. Here is the relevant part of the calendar code:

```
import static com.example.alumnos.alumni.Fragments.CreateEventsFragments.EventsTypesFragment3.eventDescription;
import static com.example.alumnos.alumni.Fragments.CreateEventsFragments.EventsTypesFragment3.eventTile;
import static com.example.alumnos.alumni.Fragments.CreateEventsFragments.EventTypesFragment.idTypeEvent;

public class Calendar_Fragment extends Fragment {
    public GregorianCalendar cal_month, cal_month_copy;
    private HwAdapter hwAdapter;
    private TextView tv_month;
    private String tipo;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        switch (idTypeEvent){
            case 1: tipo = "Evento";
                break;
            case 2: tipo = "Oferta de trabajo";
                break;
            case 3: tipo = "Notificación";
                break;
            case 4: tipo = "Noticias";
                break;

        }
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calendary, container, false);

        HomeCollection.date_collection_arr=new ArrayList<HomeCollection>();
          HomeCollection.date_collection_arr.add( new HomeCollection("2019-03-12" ,eventTile,tipo,eventDescription));
```

With this code is obviously going to overwrite every time I create an event, but I don't know how to make it that it doesn't.